# How to create a blob container in Azure using Python?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

```
I am a novice in Python programming and trying to create a blob container using python. Even after following the documented steps, I see the below error.

Here is my code:
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,BlobClient,ContainerClient,__version__


class BlobSamples():
    print("Azure Blob Storage v" + __version__ + " - Python quickstart sample")
    connection_str = os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING')
    print("Connection established to Azure storage account from the Python App")

    #--Begin Blob Samples-----------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_container_sample(self):
        # Instantiate a new BlobServiceClient using a connection string
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(self.connection_str)
        
        # Instantiate a new ContainerClient
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("mycontainer")

        try:
            # Create new container in the service
            container_client.create_container()
            # List containers in the storage account
            list_response = blob_service_client.list_containers()
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:')
            print(ex)
#main program
sample = BlobSamples()
sample.create_container_sample()



**Error:**
```

py ConnectionString.py
Azure Blob Storage v12.9.0 - Python quickstart sample
Connection established to Azure storage account from the Python App
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Technical docs\cloud computing\MS Azure\blob-quickstart-v12\menu-driven-strg-ops\ConnectionString.py", line 31, in 
sample.create_container_sample()
File "C:\Technical docs\cloud computing\MS Azure\blob-quickstart-v12\menu-driven-strg-ops\ConnectionString.py", line 16, in create_container_sample
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(self.connection_str)
File "C:\Python-InstallPath\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob_blob_service_client.py", line 174, in from_connection_string
`enter code here`account_url, secondary, credential = parse_connection_str(conn_str, credential, 'blob')
File "C:\Python-InstallPath\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob_shared\base_client.py", line 363, in parse_connection_str
conn_str = conn_str.rstrip(";")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Comment: Can you try by changing `self.connection_str` to just `connection_str`?

Comment: blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_str)
NameError: name 'connection_str' is not defined   ----It doesnt work if we dont call with self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are trying to retrieve the `connection_str` with `os.getenv`. However, if the `connection_str` is not a environment value this method returns `None` which is probably the case since your error states `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'`.

Adding the `connection_str` to your environment variables will probably solve your error. Alternatively, you can also create an argument for the `connection_str` in the `create_container_sample()` method and then passing the `connection_str` as a variable for the sake of testing your code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the scenario in my system.

Please check with you added the environment variables properly. Use
`'URL' in os.environ` to check environment present or not (true or false)

Add Environment variable in command prompt

```
set URL=https://pythonazurestorage12345.blob.core.windows.net
```

set

Try with this code

```
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,BlobClient,ContainerClient,__version__

print('URL' in os.environ)

connection_str = os.getenv("URL")
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_str)
        
        # Instantiate a new ContainerClient
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("testcontainers")
container_client.create_container()
```

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Successfully created container in Azure Portal

[image]

Comment: I tried with your code and still see the same issue. I tried to see if the connection string env variable is causing the issue. I ran the below code.

import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,BlobClient,ContainerClient,__version__


print('URL' in os.environ)

connection_str = os.getenv("URL")


It returned false.

However i dont understand as i set the env variable

Comment: @aravindhchimtamneedi  print('URL' in os.environ) is returning false means not  set the env variable,Set the env variable properly and run the code again

Comment: appreciate your help.
I fixed the env variable issue and now that i see the below error.
True
https://pystrgdemo10112021.blob.core.windows.net
Traceback (most recent call last) blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_str)e-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_service_client.py", line 174, in from_connection_string
    account_url, secondary, credential = parse_connection_str(conn_str, credential, 'blob')    raise ValueError("Connection string is either blank or malformed.")
ValueError: Connection string is either blank or malformed.

Comment: I even used connection string from access keys instead of the storage account DNS.
I was encountered with the error below
File "C:\Python-InstallPath\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\base_client.py", line 333, in send
    return self._transport.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python-InstallPath\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\transport\_requests_basic.py", line 330, in send
    raise error
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A5EB909220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: can you please provide the connection string format?

Comment: Here is how I set the connection string in env variable.
set URL="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=pystrgdemo10112021;AccountKey=mvAqJUyNvR1qxSJWhV/ol2PL9G6H8/dW6scY91gtukDoMHtBZOk3qBo8rcDtxWVHkTpv3OXa2MlpoYJ9d/R8dA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

Comment: can you try once without using env variable ? like passing connection string directly `connection_string ="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=pystrgdemo10112021;AccountKey=mvAqJUyNvR1qxSJWhV/ol2PL9G6H8/dW6scY91gtukDoMHtBZOk3qBo8rcDtxWVHkTpv3OXa2MlpoYJ9d/R8dA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string) `

Comment: Yes shruti, This works when providing the connection string value directly in the code.
There must be an issue with the privileges on the system I use, Might be an issue in setting env variables. Thanks a lot for the help:)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error and with no solution. Until I read the documentation from the Azure, they slighly changed something.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

```
setx AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING "<yourconnectionstring>"
```

After this you need to restart your editor. And everything will work. :)